# Linq - group by multiple column not working, lambda syntax

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to group 7 objects (of Type ABPM) by date and hour and not getting correct results.

```
Private Class ABPM
    Public DT As Date = Date.Now
    Public Hour As Integer = 0
    Public Minute As Integer = 0
    Public SBP As Integer = 0
    Public DBP As Integer = 0
End Class

Dim abpms As New List(Of ABPM)
```

[The data in the list is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO0Dd.jpg)

The following query produces 7 groups instead of 2

```
Dim hourlyDayGroup2 = abpms.GroupBy(Function(a As ABPM) New With {a.DT, a.Hour})
```

But this one (without lambda) outputs only 2 group which is correct

```
Dim hourlyDayGroup = From a As ABPM In abpms _
                         Group By a.DT, a.Hour Into Group
```

What is the correct way to write the lambda query? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make your anonymous type use `Key` properties, so that they participate in equality computations:

```
Dim hourlyDayGroup2 = abpms.GroupBy(Function(a As ABPM) New With {Key a.DT, Key a.Hour})
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx):

> Key properties differ from non-key properties in several fundamental ways:
>
> - Only the values of key properties are compared in order to determine whether two instances are equal.
> - The values of key properties are read-only and cannot be changed.
> - Only key property values are included in the compiler-generated hash code algorithm for an anonymous type.

Note that in C#, all properties of anonymous types have the same semantics as key properties in VB.